# Understanding Wordpress database schema - querying from 3rd party app

Tags: wordpress

Is there an easy way to grab the latest posts out of a Wordpress `wp_posts` table using a simple SQL query?

I have a Wordpress 2.9.2 installation as part of, but separate from, a larger system. It has a customized theme to look like the rest of the site but has otherwise nothing to do with it. I want to display the latest handful of headlines of posts made using Wordpress on a site of that other system. Preferably I do not want to mess around with importing any of the Wordpress library files.

Looking at the database structure I can't see an easy, straight-forward query to simply get the latest revision of the latest posts. The `post_status` can either be "post" or "inherit", the `post_type` "post" or "revision" and the parent "0" or the id of the original post of a revision. I can't figure out how to reliably filter different revisions of the same post, drafts, attachments and pages out of this mess and just get the latest revision of the latest posts.

I'm aware that the database schema is subject to change in subsequent versions of Wordpress, so shouldn't be relied upon, but that's a minor concern, since it's such a minor feature that could easily be fixed. If I understood how that database is supposed to work, that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for all posts where post_status = publish and post_type = post.

The WordPress posts table also includes pages, revisions, and attachments ... that's why you need to be specific.

If you're using the default database scheme (with `wp_` as a table prefix), the following query will give you what you need:

`SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' ORDER BY post_date DESC`

This will give you a list of the most recent headlines (post titles) of *published* posts ordered by date (with the most recent at the top).  No need to import any core WordPress libraries.  Just make sure not to accidentally tweak the database while accessing it directly or you might break something in WordPress.

Comment: Alright, I see. I was under the mistaken impression that an "inherited revision" may be newer than a "published post". Thanks for clearing that up!